# number_format() ожидает

Tags: php

подскажите пожалуйста, что может вызывать такую ошибку - ,,Warning: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be double, string given,,
Ссылается на эту строку -

```
case 1: $b=number_format($a,$y,"."," "); break;
```

весь код -

```
function _font($a, $r=0, $f=0, $y=0)
{
if($a)  
    {
    switch ($r)
        {
        case 0: $b=number_format($a,$y,",",""); break;
        case 1: $b=number_format($a,$y,"."," "); break;
        case 2: $b=number_format($a,$y,",","."); break;
        case 3: $b=number_format($a,$y,".",","); break;
        case 4: $b=number_format($a,$y,".",""); break;
        }

    switch ($f)
        {
        case 0: $c=$b; break;
        case 1: $c="<font color=#FF0000>".$b."</font>"; break;
        case 2: $c="<font color=#660033>".$b."</font>"; break;
        case 3: $c="<font color=#009966>".$b."</font>"; break;
        case 4: $c="<font color=#0066CC>".$b."</font>"; break;
        }
    }
else $c='';
return $c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто переобразуйте значение аргумента `$a` в тип `float`:

```php
number_format((float)$a,$y,",","");
```

Comment: Спасибо MyZik , все заработало.

Comment: Сейчас пишет только цифры, ошибки не какой не выводит, код в первоначальном виде. Как сделать что бы писал буквы ?